# using a setInterval within a class and then making multiple of those classes javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have a class with a loop in it that I want to run every 50 milliseconds but with using setInterval you can't do this.loop() because then its trying to find loop() from with in the setInterval function but not the class so I did `self=this` then `setinterval(function(){self.loop()})` which work all well and good untill i made 2 of them so then only one of them had the loop running

code:

```
enemy = function(){
 self=this
 setinterval(function(){self.loop()})

 this.loop=function(){
  code
 }
}

enemy1 = new enemy
enemy2 = new enemy
```

so how can i have so enemy1 and 2 have the loop working and not just enemy2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing variable declarations with `var` everywhere.

What it means is that global variables are created. It's not critical for `enemy`, `enemy1` and `enemy2` variables.

But the variable `self` becomes shared for all instances.

So the fix: always declare your variables with `var`.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. :)

```js
var enemy = function(){
  _SELF = this;
  _SELF.loop = function(){
    // your code
    if(true) _SELF.loop(); // add a condition to stop the loop!
  }
}

var enemy1 = new enemy();
var enemy2 = new enemy();
var enemy3 = new enemy();
```